# tend to be vs tend to do

Tags: grammar

1. As most men tend to be, I'm willing to play games at home.
2. As most men tend to do, I'm willing to play games at home.

I wonder which one is grammatically correct.

I think 1 is correct because "willing" can be regarded as implied as in "As most men tend to be willing".

Maybe could sentence 2 correct if we think "do" is substituted for "play" as in "tend to do"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, *be* is associated with a state (adjective), while *do* is associated with an action (verb).

As suggested, *be* and *willing* go together. But *do* and *willing* don't.

So, we have the following pair of sentences (I am removing the contraction to make this more obvious):

> ✔ As most men tend to ***be***, I *am* **willing** to play games at home.
>   ✘ As most men tend to ***do***, I *am* **willing** to play games at home.

But we could change this to remove *willing*, which would reverse the situation:

> ✘ As most men tend to ***be***, I **play** games at home.
>   ✔ As most men tend to ***do***, I **play** games at home.

Comment: Maybe do even native speakers often make this kind of mistake that they say or write "do" instead of "be"?

Comment: @SinK I'm sure that *some* make a mistake in usage. Especially in speech, native speakers *say* things that are wrong all the time. (Myself included, although hopefully not that often.) As for how *common* it is to make such a mistake, I couldn't say.